# Symbology Standards

Tags: symbology, standards, arcgis-water-utilities

I was recently assigned a task to figure out if there are anything standards for symbology when it comes to mapping utilities like water, sewer, and storm. I have looked online but yet to find anything solid.

Do you have knowledge on this?

Comment: No, it also depends on if public/private utilities. Disclaimer in this industry ,we have our own internal standards. Esri has some https://esri-styles.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=c19eacd596794591a0fd8dd7aed38978 but we do not use ESRI...

Comment: thank you for the information.